# Need help plotting area between multivariate lines - not from axis to line

Tags: d3.js, linechart, stream-graph

I'm brand new to d3.js, and I'm struggling to fill in the area between lines in a multivariate percentile graph.

- I don't want any area filled below the bottom most line, or above the top most line.
- The first column will always be at the bottom of the graph (5th percentile)
- The last column will always be at the top of the graph (95th percentile)
- I need separate area segments between each line

I know I need to define an area to fill between (y0, y1) like so:

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y0(function(d) { return y(BOTTOM); })
.y1(function(d) { return y(TOP); });
```

However I can't figure out what to put in for the .y1 section.  Ideally, I'd just grab the next value of the next row in the TSV, but I don't know how to do this properly.

For testing purposes, I have the following which creates ONE of the area segments I need:

```
.y0(function(d) { return y(+d.p05); })
.y1(function(d) { return y(+d.p25); });
```

---

I want something like this, but this example doesn't help since it isn't referencing a different row from a csv/tsv:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060954

[image]

This one is similar, but its bivariate, not multivariate.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3894205

[image]

---

Here's my work in progress(view source):

http://artfuladvection.com/project/NOAA/percentilesGraph/multipercentile.html

My TSV is setup like this:

```
date    p05 p25 p50 p75 p95
20140122    3   4   5   6   12
20140123    9   10  12  22  34
20140124    14  16  18  34  66
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single area, the code would look something like this.

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
  .y0(function(d) { return y(+d.p05); })
  .y1(function(d) { return y(+d.p25); });

per.append("g")
   .attr("class", "per")
   .append("path")
   .attr("class", "area")
   .attr("d", function (d) { return area(data); });
```

For multiple areas, you can use the domain of your `color` scale to loop over the different values like you have done before. That is, the code above would be in a loop like this.

```
var values = color.domain();
for(var i = 0; i < values.length() - 1; i ++) {
  var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(function(d) { return y(+d[values[i]]); })
    .y1(function(d) { return y(+d[values[i+1]]); });

  per.append("g")
     .attr("class", "per-" + values[i])
     .append("path")
     .attr("class", "area-" + values[i])
     .attr("d", function (d) { return area(data); });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, however this creates an area between the top and bottom most line. I suppose I didn't clarify I wanted separate area segments between each of the lines. See: http://artfuladvection.com/project/NOAA/percentilesGraph/multipercentilev2.html

Comment: That did help me figure out how to create ONE of the area segments I wanted (see original WIP link), but I don't quite understand how to create the rest of them.

Comment: Right, sorry, that wasn't clear to me. Will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks Lars! I think that did it -- I need to fix the colors for each segment to make sure (I don't know how to do that yet either, heh), and I'll accept.